# Pull Request Best Practises?

Tags: git, github

I'm working on a project using GitHub as part of a small organisation (~10 contributors). As with most projects, we make changes on a forked copy of the repo and submit pull requests which the higher-ups then review. The policy for my group is that all code changes, no matter how minor, should happen only after a pull request.

As such, I recently added a single field to one of our databases and despite feeling a full pull-request + code review was overkill, I followed the protocol anyway. This feels massively inefficient - am I right, or is this the norm for most organisations?

Answer (score 1):

It is the norm and you should not push and deploy code without going through this process.

Often, a pull request can also trigger a pipeline that will run a test job to ensure that the code is still working.

A single change of code could break everything so this is important that at least one person review it.

It is also useful so other developers can keep up to date with the latest changes in code even if they are small changes, so they don't assume the code is doing something else since they didn't checked the file you've changed recently.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to contributing answers but here's the tip.

If you want a best pull request in your organisation, try to assign a meaningful title; then assign members who want to see the files changed; if possible assign at least one reviewer. Because, without reviewing code, it would be meaningless. (I've done that mistake and eventually learned it)

Then finally, in the files changed tab, comment the lines of code and start a review. That would make a better pull request in the repo.

Comment: You seemed confused on this one....